# SAPUI5 - Dateformat - How format a date with Dateformat

Tags: date, format, sapui5

let's say I have a Date as a String, formated in `yyyy-MM-dd`, and I want it to be formated as `style:"short"`.
I want just to use `Dateformat`.

I used this https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f2eba36f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html to get an idea of how to use `DateFormat`.

But I can't see, what's wrong with my code:

```
date: function(sdate) {
   var regex = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}";
   if (!sdate.match(regex))
    return "no valid date given";

   jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat");
   var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getInstance({pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd", style: "short"});
   return oDateFormat.format(sdate); //date should be returned here in "short"-style
}
```

The console tell's me
`TypeError: j.getTime is not a function`.
Also it seems like the WebIDE doesn't know a function `Datetime.format()`.

Can you help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to Date in SAPUI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343915/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-sapui5)

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably reread the documentation in your link: to convert String into JS Date, you have to use `DateFormat.parse` method.